# How to get the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

In LAMP, I get the root of the website with

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

as in `/some/path/public_html`

How do I get this, in coldfusion?

Update: I find that on this server, '/' is the doc root (and not the root of the whole file system, like LAMP)  Is that reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ColdFusion really has no idea where the 'web root' is, not should it really matter. I often architect applications where all my controllers, services and files are outside of the web root. What I tend to do in those cases where I actually need to know the web root I will create a ColdFusion mapping in my Application.cfc file that looks like this:

```
rootDir = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath());
this.mappings[ "/www" ] = rootDir;
this.mappings[ "/services" ] = rootDir & '../services';
```

This will create 2 ColdFusion mappings named `www` and `services` respectively pointing to the 'web root' (my `www` directory) and `services` directory above the web root. My directory structure would look something like this:

- Site Directory

  - wwwapp

    - services
    - www (web root)

Comment: does 'this' have a meaning, in cf?  As in php's $this (refers to the current class)

Answer (score 0):

I normally use

```
ExpandPath('/')
```

but I strongly suggest to check it on a server by server basis.

Also, please notice that this funcion returns the ending slash:

```
/var/www/html/
```